# Configure apache to redirect url to another host

Tags: apache, proxypass

**Configuration:** I have 2 virtual machines:

- **VM1**: accessible from browser with https://vm1.com
- **VM2**: accessible from browser with 10.200.200.200:8088

**What I want to do:**

==> If the user will enter this url: https://vm1.com/dashboard

==> The flow will be redirected to 10.200.200.200:8088

**What I try to do:**

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerAdmin me@mydomain.com
  DocumentRoot /var/www

  ProxyPreserveHost On
  ProxyRequests Off
  ProxyPass /dashboard http://10.200.200.200:8088/
  ProxyPassReverse /dashboard http://10.200.200.200:8088/

  <Directory /var/www/>
      Options +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
      AllowOverride All
      Require all granted
  </Directory>

  ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
  CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

</VirtualHost>
```

**Problem:**

This solution works only if the incoming url is /dashboard. If the incoming url is /dashboard/login, the redirect failed.